# Replace one character with many with regex

Tags: regex, replace, sed

There are a lot of ways to replace many characters with one.

```
s/a\{100\}/a/
```

Is there any way to replace it vice versa (one `a` with hundred `a`) without typing `a` 100 times?

ps. I use regexes in `sed`.

Comment: write a script to loop over it?  I don't think you can do it from within the regex

Comment: I think it is not part of the design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
sed ':x;/a\{100\}/b;s/a/aa/;tx'
```

Comment: Ok, seems there is no way in pure regexes. Therefore I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly as terse as you would like, but you could do something like this:

```
sed -e 's/a/aaaaaaaaaa/' -e 's/\(aaaaaaaaaa\)/\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1/'
```

Basically replace the original `a` with 10 of them, then replace the sequence of 10 with 10 copies. For numbers other than 100, obviously, you'd factor it differently.

Comment: It can be much shorter: `sed 's/a/aaaaaaaaaa/;s/a\{10\}/&&&&&&&&&&/'`. =) Unfortunately seems there is no another way.

Comment: Right... forgot about `&`. And the separate `-e` argument thing is just a personal preference - I think it makes it easier to decipher what's going on. But of course, once I've got it working write and am putting it into a script, combining it all into one arg makes more sense...